# How to sum up agent parameter during batch process

Tags: anylogic

I am batching agents using batch block .
My agent has parameter value. when I am batching it , I want to add the parameter values and assign it to new batch agent created.

> agent1 - 50, agent2- 70, agent3 - 30 ;

If I want to batch these three agents then new aggregated agent should have a value of 150 ( sum of all agent's value)

Answer (score 0):

on the on add action of your batch block you do this

```
batch.parameter+=agent.parameter;
```